# With the Pi Zero W plus a 2.4A adapter, can I safely draw up to 2A from the 5V pin?

Tags: power, power-supply, pi-zero-w

Since the Zero W doesn't have a polyfuse, am I right in assuming that the 5V pin can safely supply whatever current the power supply puts out minus the draw from the Zero W board itself (and any attached items)?

I'd like to power 4x devices with a max draw of 500mA each. My power supply provides 2400mA. [According to this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs), the typical bare board consumption is 150mA. I don't have any USB devices attached which means I end up with 2400-500*4-150 = 250mA overhead if all 4 devices are on full load.

Is this correct? Is there any reason not to do this?

Comment: Your calculation is OK. Who knows how much current the board traces can  "safely" handle.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about that. I suppose it would be better to solder wires directly to the USB power connector, and use those wires to power the 4 devices?

Comment: I guess there's also the option of powering the pi directly from the 5v pin and gnd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would power from the 5V pin to minimize the current flowing through the Pi traces.

For my experiments I would actually apply power to a breadboard rail and take power from there to a Pi 5V pin.  I'd also power the external devices from the breadboard rail.

Of course the Pi and devices also need to be connected to a breadboard ground rail.